# Convert video files to supported formats and with correct codec to reproduce on Epson projector

Tags: ffmpeg, projector, avi

I have the [EPSON EH-DM3 projector](http://pdf.myprojectorlamps.com/projector-manuals/pdf/EPSON/EPSON%20EH-DM3.pdf) and it supports the following formats only:

[image]

and here are more specific info:

[image]

now I'd like to be able to reproduce my videos on it by simply converting them before reproducing on the projector.

I use Linux, what command could I use to convert a video?
I think I should re-encode any video to `.avi` right?
Is there a general command I can use for all my video files and that does not required too much time to convert?

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -profile:v mpeg4_asp -vf scale=720x576 output.avi
```

but the projector keeps saying `Codec is not supported` when entering the USB drive and trying to reproduce the video.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Share the *full* command and log.

Comment: hi @Gyan, what log do you need? The error I get is from the projector not from the `ffmpeg` command

Comment: Have you tried other profiles, or lowering the bit-rate? Also depending on your source material you may have to check your pixel format—use `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to make sure.

Comment: The log has details about the input as well as the various choices ffmpeg makes. This can help to diagnose.

Comment: @Gyan no matter what video I convert, I just don't understand from those specifications what type of codec / bitrate etc... I need to set to `ffmpeg` in order to make the projector read it, that's why I'm asking to more expert people about the topic